# Using Event.target.id as a way of sending data up the component chain

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items and I want to bring some data from a child component to the "source of truth", which items have been selected in this case, but the only way I can think of of specifying which list item has been selected is but using the event.target.id property. of which I specify in one of the child components. see below

```
    constructor(props){ 
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            showDialog : false,
            preparedSpells: [],
        }
}

    onPrep(e){
        let prepedSpells = this.state.preparedSpells
        let targetSpell = Number(e.target.id)

        if (prepedSpells.includes(targetSpell)){
            let index = prepedSpells.indexOf(targetSpell)
            prepedSpells.splice(index,1)
        } else {
            prepedSpells.push(targetSpell)
        }

        this.setState({
            prepedSpells : prepedSpells
            })


    render(){
       
         return(
            <SpellList spells = {this.spells} onSpellClick = {this.onSpellClick} onClick = {this.onPrep}></SpellList>
         );
```

I need the data to be at this level but I feel that there should be a way of setting the state in one of the list item components and then iterating through them all to find which are selected.

I know data only flows down in react but is there something im missing? or should I bottle up this feeling of wrongness

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're pretty close to correctness to me.

Let me tell you what I would change:
Instead of sending passing the whole event to "onPrep", you can just pass the id.

```
onPrep(targetSpell){
    let prepedSpells = this.state.preparedSpells

    if (prepedSpells.includes(targetSpell)){
        let index = prepedSpells.indexOf(targetSpell)
        prepedSpells.splice(index,1)
    } else {
        prepedSpells.push(targetSpell)
    }

    this.setState({
        prepedSpells : prepedSpells
    })
```

And I don't actually have the code for the SpellList component, but you should have something like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.props.spells.map((spell) => {
      return <button onClick={() => {this.props.onClick(spell.id)}}>{spell.name}</button>;
    })}
  </div>
);
```

That way you can pass whatever you want to the click event handler, and it makes things look cleaner.